# SQL Server : Not able to get results using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

Please see below image for table data - Table Name : TempRecords.

[image]

1. Columns Date,Value are input.
2. Columns Previous Date, Value2 should be output.

Requirement is  :Find Previous Date of Date Column and get Value of that previous date from the same table.

I have such table in SQL and I am trying to achieve this result using `Select from Select` or `CTE` query. 
But I am not able to get results.

Comment: Add your query to the post, let us see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well you have already Previous Date column in the table with Value2 available. What exactly you want and how? Please elaborate it more.

Comment: Also, please explain a little more what you're trying to achieve. It is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(CURRENTDATE DATE,VALUE INT)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES('02/03/2010',NULL),
                        ('05/04/2010',NULL),
                        ('5/5/2010',10),
                        ('5/6/2010',20),
                        ('5/7/2010',30)


SELECT T2.CURRENTDATE,
       T2.VALUE, 
       DATEADD(DAY, -1,T2.CURRENTDATE) AS PREVIOUSDATE,
       T1.VALUE AS VALUE2
FROM #TEMP T2 LEFT JOIN #TEMP T1 ON T1.CURRENTDATE = DATEADD(DAY, -1,T2.CURRENTDATE)
```

[image: Output]